# Failed to determine a suitable driver class - Spring Boot- PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot

I am trying to connect a Postgres DB to my Spring Boot aplication, but I get the following error:

> Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.
> Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
>
> Action:
> Consider the following:
> If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
> If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).

application.yaml

```
datasource:
  driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
  url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/my_db
  username: postgres
  password: pswrd
# JPA properties
jpa:
  hibernate:
    ddl-auto: update # When you launch the application for the first time - switch "none" at "create"
  show-sql: true
  database: my_db
  database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
  open-in-view: false
  generate-ddl: true
```

Project structure:

[image]

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>PostgresApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>PostgresApp</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: I sure hope you are not really using the superuser (`postgres`) from within your application. That would be a really, really bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be missing the `spring` prefix from all of the properties in your `application.yaml`. It should be the following:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/my_db
    username: postgres
    password: pswrd
  # JPA properties
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update # When you launch the application for the first time - switch "none" at "create"
    show-sql: true
    database: my_db
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    open-in-view: false
    generate-ddl: true
```